# How to Dynamically assemble SQL queries with haskell based on route parameters

Tags: haskell, postgresql-simple

I've got a scotty web app that I am trying to implement a dynamic search interface over and keep hitting a wall on how I should implement it. The Basic premise is the following:

Given a list of URL parameters: `let params = [Param]`

where param: `type Param = (Text, Text)`

I would like to be able to

Lets say I have a table in my database where:

```
Users
| user_id | username | email | first_name | last_name | created_at |
|---------|----------|-------|------------|-----------|------------|
|   Int   |  Text    | Text  |  Text      | Text      | timestamp  |
```

My base SQL query might look like this:

```
baseQuery :: Query
baseQuery :: [sql| SELECT user_id, username, email, first_name, last_name, created_at FROM users |]
```

In the case of receiving url parameters I would want to be able to apply them to the WHERE clause, ORDER BY clause, etc.

What would be the best strategy to transform the following url:

```
arbitraryhost:/users?order_by_max=user_id&first_name=emg184&last_name=stackoverflow&limit=20
```

which would result in the following parameters list:

`let params = [("order_by_max","user_id"), ("first_name","emg184"), ("last_name","stackoverflow"), ("limit", "20")]`

How would i generate the follwing query:

```
"SELECT user_id, username, email, first_name, last_name, created_at 
FROM users
WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?
ORDER BY user_id
LIMIT ?"

("emg184", "stackoverflow", 20)
```

(I really like the way that the query builder knexjs works which allows for ad hoc fragments of queries to be generated and applied as a higher order function to some base query http://knexjs.org/)

Im wondering what a strategy or implementation of this might be as I have not been successful in building anything that I find to be very fitting for this.